# Parsing JSON data with Python

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I receive some data from a GitHub webhook service. It contains info about recent commits in a repository. String I receive looks like this:

```
payload = {
    "ref":"refs/heads/master","commits":[
        {"added":[],"author":{"username":"myname","email":"my@email.com","name":"John Doe"},"timestamp":"2011-03-03T02:04:32-08:00","removed":[],"url":"https://github.com/repository/commit/3da6de4ae4550aa84ff16b9b52d8c5179e126dc5","message":"Setup some functions","modified":["apps/api/__init__.py","main.py","utils.py"],"id":"3da6de4ae4550aa84ff16b9b52d8c5179e126dc5"}
    ],
    "compare":"https://github.com/repository/compare/a270fe9...eb26a23","after":"eb26a2312e1955ccb2b7cb50d43682be87c30faa","repository":{"pushed_at":"2011/03/03 02:23:14 -0800","has_issues":true,"has_downloads":true,"url":"https://github.com/repository","watchers":1,"fork":false,"has_wiki":true,"private":false,"size":2248,"forks":1,"created_at":"2011/02/23 04:41:51 -0800","owner":{"email":"my@email.com","name":"john"},"name":"john","language":"Python","open_issues":0},"forced":false,"before":"a270fe954359caa323a9880afc3d6301055ea566"
}
```

What is the right way to remove that variable `payload=` and get only the data between `{}` so that it would be a correct JSON that I can parse with `simplejson`? Now I just use `json_data = json_data.replace('payload=', '')`. I am not sure it's a right way to do this. How can I do it a better way? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I posted a [message](http://support.github.com/discussions/post-receive-issues/178-post-receive-hook-json-post) on GitHub support board with the issue description.

Comment: It might also be worth bugging Github to return valid JSON - it might be a bug at their end.

Comment: How do you receive it? Is it in a HTTP response or a HTTP post?

Comment: GitHub sends a POST to the url I provide there in settings. It's described here: http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/. So, It sends a POST with a string in my question.

Comment: Definitely worth bugging github as @Thomas suggests, since there's no sign of a variable in any of their samples on that page.

Comment: @Nick: Well, in fact there is. "This is sent as a POST with a single parameter: ‘payload’". In fact is's being sent as an HTTP form, so the correct way to do it is to handle it as such - I think there's something in the `cgi` module for it. But that's possibly overkill here.

Comment: @Thomas But the example just below that doesn't show the payload argument. And this is JSONP, not a form.

Comment: @Nick: `JSON.parse(params[:payload])`. And it can't be JSONP, because that's an HTTP response to an XHR - here the content is delivered as an HTTP request.

Comment: @Thomas But none of the snippets, including @Sergey 's, are urlencoded, which they would be if it was form data.

Comment: @Nick: I assume they're showing the plain JSON to make it easier to read. All you do with the form encoded data is decode it and get the payload value.

Comment: @Thomas But they don't make any mention of formencoding or urlencoding anywhere, and they just say "this is an example of the payload".

Comment: @Nick: Well, it's pretty clear that that is what they're doing. Sergey's question on Github support got the same answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look for the first { character:

```
jsondata = jsondata[jsondata.index("{"):]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no single "right" way of doing it, unless you want to implement a complete JS parser. That said, the solution suggested by Thomas is more generalizable, eg. less likely to break if github decides to change the format of the file, if you use it on a different data source, etc.