# Parsing response from Github

Tags: python

How do I make string like `"payload={'key':'value'...}"` to become a variable `payload` with value assigned to it `"{'key':'value'...}"`? Thanks.

Comment: The big question is: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I had another question here:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181147/parsing-json-data-with-python). I also received an answer on GitHub board where I got a reply: _You're correct, the POST request is form encoded, with the payload value being the JSON. Don't just scan for a { though, actually parse it with a python form parser._ So now I suppose I need to go this way.

Comment: See my answer on how to actualy parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like they said on github, use a query string parser, like this:

```
import urlparse
str = "payload={'key':'value'}"
print urlparse.parse_qs(str)
```

Result is this:

```
{'payload': ["{'key':'value'}"]}
```

Comment: If it's the thing described in http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/ it's the right thing to do

Comment: That gets you as far as the string `"{'key':'value'}"`, which you then need to parse using the `json` library.

Comment: Hm, since which version of Python `parse_qs` is available? GAE uses 2.5 and may be it's not available there. So, it's another problem then.

Comment: According to the manual, it was copied from the cgi module since 2.6. So just use the cgi module in stead of the urlparse module.

Answer (score 0):

```
payload = json.loads(jsonstring)
payload = pickle.loads(pickstring)
```

Don't pickle untrusted data.

Comment: The string does not look like JSON. *Edit: It does definitely not work*.

Comment: Strip the payload= from the front and you could trick it into thinking its json

Comment: Well, maybe you should explain this. But the approach is very error prone. The value has to meet the exact requirements for JSON syntax, which the above string does not (single quotes instead of double quotes). It could also contain `None` which needed to be transformed to `null` or `"None"`.... I think this is more work than you think. Also you have to create the `payload` variable dynamically which you don't do. `eval` and `exec` might be dangerous, but until now they provide the only working solution.